# Async Parallel & Request Package returning API results out of order (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, request

I currently have an asynchronous API call that makes at this moment 19 different request to a string end-point using the async & request NPM packages.  I just discovered that towards the end of my requests, the actual object that is being returned is the data for the request prior.  Here is an example of my code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel([
        function(next) {
            request(queryString + 'end point link', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var variable0 = JSON.parse(body);
                    return next(null, variable0);
        };
        console.log(error);

        next(error);
    });
},
        function(next) {
            request(queryString + 'end point link', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var variable19 = JSON.parse(body);
                    return next(null, variable19);

        };
        console.log(error);
        next(error);
    });
    }], 
        function(err, results) {
        res.render("view", { 
            variable0: results[0],
            variable1: results[1], 
            variable2: results[2],  
            ......
            ......
            variable19: results[19]
        });        
    });    
});
```

This was working perfectly until I noticed my last three variables (lets call them 17, 18 and 19) were returning the results of the prior API call. I'm unsure why this is occurring, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The results variable async provides is an array, which I've modified into an object at a given index for the appropriate request.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I missed a faulty request in my code.  Issue has been solved. Thanks SO.